# PL/SQL Trigger and multiple updates

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, relational-database

I've written a Trigger that only allows an update to a products price if it is at least 10% above cost. It appears to be working when I update one products price, however I need it to be able to update multiple products at once. Any suggestions? Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
create or replace TRIGGER P_check
BEFORE UPDATE ON ProductCat
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:new.ListPrice < :old.TotalCost * 1.1) THEN
 raise_application_error (-20500, :new.ListPrice || ' is too low so the price stays '  ||:old.ListPrice);
 ELSE
 dbms_output.put_line ('Price was updated and the new price is ' || :new.ListPrice);
 END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. You have the trigger defined as `FOR EACH ROW`; thus, your trigger will be invoked for each row changed in `ProductCat`.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Sadly is does not work. When I run something like this: UPDATE ProductCat SET listPrice = 200; The trigger starts the application error (because 200 is too small of a number for the first value). Then, the output.put_line is displayed saying it updated the price of the various items (but it really did not). However, If I choose a large value, such as productcatalog1 SET listPrice = 5000; it works because the application error never goes off.

Comment: My professor has hinted that I need to use something like :new. := :old. to solve this problem, but I do not understand

Comment: Did you commit the changes?

Comment: Bob, what did you mean by that? When I change it to 5000, yes the values of listPrice change.

Comment: When you raise an exception there's an implied rollback; thus, no changes. So - you need to come up with a way, using your prof's suggestion, to revert the change without raising an exception. Give it some thought. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I was able to get it working by removing the raise_application error and using :new.ListPrice := :old.ListPrice; instead.